# How to create a placeholder in table name in databricks

Tags: sql, databricks

Hope the title clarifies what I actually want. I will try to describe the problem.

I am looking for something like this :

```
variable = "1"
%sql 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS database.table_{variable}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access python variable in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794549/how-can-i-access-python-variable-in-spark-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Spark SQL within Python notebook you can easily achieve this with strings as below -

```
%python

spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS database.table_{variable}".format(variable=variable))
```

Alternatively, you can follow the link below achieving the same using SQL as well -

[Assign a variable a dynamic value in SQL in Databricks / Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277255/assign-a-variable-a-dynamic-value-in-sql-in-databricks-spark)